# UK horror comic story about a boy with a broken arm and an insectoid twist

Tags: story-identification, comics, horror

I can remember the following details: a young boy is sent to live with his aunt while recovering from a broken arm. To his surprise, most of the people in the town have plaster casts as well. I think a meteor may have landed nearby recently.

A visit to church shows people having their casts removed, revealing insectoid body parts, much to the joy of the congregation.

The story ends with the boy in the hospital, having his own cast removed, revealing that he too has an insect arm.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: When did you read this? Do you remember the comic format (colour / b&w) or size (A4 like 2000AD or the smaller American format)? Was this the only story in the comic?

Answer (score 1):

It's the one-off story called [“A break in the country"](http://www.backfromthedepths.co.uk/issues/issue5.html) that appeared in issue #5 of the short-lived (and excellent!) British Horror comic, *Scream*.

As you can see (from the link), there is a meteor shower over Britain, the protagonist, Tony Crabtree, a young teenage boy, has broken his leg and is traveling by train to see his aunt while he recuperates. When he arrives he notices that everybody appears to be injured in some way, including his aunt, all with limbs (or in a couple of cases, whole heads) bandaged up.

He becomes suspicious, especially the next day when his aunt has both her arm and her leg bandaged up, but she drags him to the ruined church in the village, where everyone has gathered and a mysterious individual, covered head to toe in bandages speaks to the crowd, talking about seed pods arriving from space. He then removes his bandages to reveal that he is a large insectoid and he encourages the villagers to do the same. Everyone's bandaged limb / head is revealed to now be insectoid too.

Tony attempts to hobble away but they quickly catch him and remove the cast on his leg to find he is normal. Seeing this they close in on him, chanting "KILL!", and Tony passes out.

He awakens in hospital, relieved that it all appears to have been a vivid dream, but as they staff remove the cast from his leg, he sees in horror that they are insects and his leg is now also insectoid. Screaming, the end.